# Is "… and then" acceptable? Microsoft Word says yes, my grammar instructors say no

Tags: conjunctions

All my grammar instructors have been in agreement. Never use 'and then'. However, my word processor auto-corrects 'then' to 'and then'.

> Perform task 1, task 2, then task3.

works either way when 'then' is an adverb.

But, used as a conjunctive adverb in a compound sentence, the conjunction gets auto-corrected.

> Perform task 1, perform task 2, then perform task 3.

Auto-correct to '*and then* perform task 3.'

Who are right? The instructors or the editors of Microsoft Word?

Comment: Tell your so-called grammar instructors that they are idiots **and then** tell them to go and study some more.

Comment: @JoeDark I would upvote your comment if it had no name-calling. I'm certain that you wrote it in good faith, and I think it's effective, maybe too effective. Anyway, I'd like to suggest [this post, the Be Nice policy](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240839/the-new-new-be-nice-policy-code-of-conduct-updated-with-your-feedback).

Comment: I should point out, this was a half century, ago. The language evolves & changes over time. Did the usage of 'and then' change over time, or were the instructors - all from the Midwest - wrong when they told their students that rule?

Comment: I found this similar question on SE. Maybe it will help. http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/47226/is-it-correct-to-say-a-b-then-c-instead-of-a-b-and-then-c

Comment: @David Got it! The fact that it's a coordinating conjunction calls for the use of *and*. You just answered a question that's been haunting me for years.

Comment: When is 'then' used as a preposition? Can you provide an example?

Comment: @CarSmack You got me on two points. First, thank you for catching the typo in my title. Second, no, I can't provide an example because it's an adverb, indicating when something occurs. Neither could I show how it's used as a conjunction because it's a conjunctive adverb. Looks like I need to do some research before I spout off. Good catches on your part.

Comment: @Jim, I am also from the Midwest and learned in school to use then without an 'and'. You aren't the only one! It wasn't until I was working that I learned an 'and' is required. I do wonder if it wasn't a regionalism that just worked its way into our grammar lessons. 'Then' without the conjunction still sounds more natural to my ear and I need to remind myself to use one.

Comment: Side note: I think you mean, "Who's right?", i.e. "Who is right?" "Whose" is a possessive pronoun. "Whose right?" would mean that you are questioning who owns the right, like, "When you say 'right', do you mean the actor's right or the audience's right? Whose right is it?"

Comment: @Jay I don't know why I got it right in the title, and wrong in the question. I proofread right over it. Good catch!

Comment: @200_success Your edit is appreciated, but I take issue with "Who are right?" The instructors make up a single group & the editors make up a single group. The verb following an 'or' between two singulars would also be singular. "Which group is right?" might be a better wording. Great rewrite on the title, though. I like it.

Comment: The conjugation "who are right" came from @MaulikV. I just preserved it without thinking it through.

Comment: @Jim Who are right? The instructors or the editors? What's the problem?

Comment: @Maulik V To answer your question would address philosophies of sentence structure more than grammar, beyond the scope of this site. "Who are right," sound awkward to me, but I'll accept it. Anyway, the effort by 200_success & you to edit my post is appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

Per comments, OP's instructors are probably just incompetent (or perhaps he somehow misunderstood what they meant). In standard English, ***and*** has two distinct meanings...

> 1: *Dick liked Jane **and** she liked him*
>    2: *Dick insulted Jane **and** she slapped him*

...where #1 simply uses ***and*** to join two "independent" statements - stripped of pronoun substitutions,...

> 1a: *Dick liked Jane*
>    ***and*** (another statement, with no specific relationship to the first)
>    1b: *Jane liked Dick*

But in #2 the conjunction implies a temporal/causal relationship between the two statements...

> 2a: *Dick insulted Jane*
>    ***and*** (*subsequently* - pragmatically, probably *consequently*)
>    2b: *Jane slapped Dick*

Grammatically/semantically, the ***and*** in #2 can be replaced by ***and then*** or simply ***then***. Perhaps OP's instructors felt he was overusing the two-word form in contexts where it was pragmatically obvious that the second event was *later in time and/or caused by the preceding event*. But this is a matter of style, nothing to do with grammaticality.

---

TL;DR: Even if OP's instructors knew what they were talking about, they've obviously failed to convey the correct information to their student. The only reasons to avoid ***and then*** are (1) - if the context implies no [con]sequential relationship, and (2) - because using it *excessively* can result in a stilted prose style.

---

EDIT: In fairness to OP's instructors, they might be (mistakenly, imho) attempting to impose notions derived from *prescriptive grammar*. Consider...

> 2a: *Dick insulted Jane*
>    2c: *Then Jane slapped Dick*
>    2d: *Jane then slapped Dick*
>    2e: *Jane slapped Dick then*

...where 2c-2e are all valid sentences/clauses that could follow 2a. It's irrelevant here whether we put a period or a semicolon between 2a and whichever of 2c-2e we choose to use (you wouldn't hear a difference in speech anyway). The point is the fact that ***then*** can be moved around like this implies it's an *adverb*, not a [*coordinating conjunction*](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/conjunctions.htm). As that link says...

> *Be careful of the words **then** and **now**; neither is a "coordinating conjunction", so what we say about coordinating conjunctions' roles in a sentence and punctuation does not apply to those two words.*

I cant say I find the above caveat particularly enlightening, but it may help explain some of the antipathy directed at the usage ***and then***.

Answer (score -3):

"And then" is redundant. Regardless of what other words surround it. Dick slapped Jane and Jane slapped Dick.  Dick slapped Jane, then Jane slapped dick.  Dick slapped Jane and then Jane slapped dick.